# UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewLayout with self sizing cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building what should be a magazine with a vertically scrolling grid showing articles and other items, see screenshot.

[image: Design]

Pretty quickly it became clear that `UICollectionView` is the way to go for a layout like this.

What I’m looking for is very much the Pinterest tutorial found here: [UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial: Pinterest](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Except that I need more flexibility on the height for each cell. I managed to build what is on the screenshot via this tutorial, but with fixed cell heights.

1 thing I can not get my head around is using *self sizing cells* with Auto Layout in a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. Also because I found very little documentation or examples on it. The examples I did find are mainly about `UITableView` and `UICollectionFlowLayout`. I think I need more flexibility than just what `UICollectionFlowLayout` can do.

The thing that confuses me the most is when I can know about the actual size of a cell vs the estimated size and how/if I should then update all the cell y positions if a cell changes height. When to invalidate the layout, with what context, etc.

I want the layout to support the following:

- flexible cell heights, based on content, changing on runtime by user interaction
- changing columns on the fly, due to different screensizes/orientation changes
- support all kinds of cell types which are very configurable (there is not 1 recipe I can use to determine the height of a cell before the UI is created)
- support *a lot* of cells

This [WWDC '14 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/226/) mentions that it's possible since iOS8:  but the part on this for a custom UICollectionViewLayout is somewhat short and in my opinion not covering it all.

A lot of similar questions exist already, but mostly they are about `UITableView` and using `UICollectionViewLayout`.

I hope my story is clear enough :)

Comment: I would rethink the assumption that `UICollectionView` is a good fit. They are typically used for grid-based content where the cells are a consistent height. You can do it, but it may require substantial customization.

Comment: Fair enough. What would the alternative be? Keep in mind I'm also intending to use Core Data, NSFetchControllers etc.

Comment: CollectionView is perfectly fine fine for this layout. I wouldn't recommend going with the Self Sizing cells though. That feature seems to be developed solely for the WWDC demos.

Comment: Have you check, when screen orientation change collectionview's width is not update ?
If change there then please let me know how to change , we have apply (viewWillTransition) but it's not working here.

Comment: Have you solve self sizing.. when image download I need to relayout.. Do you have demo if than provide me please.